# How to remove a marker from existing data on a map

Tags: javascript, jquery, postgresql, maps, leaflet

I have a datset of restaurants made in postgresql and they are shown on a map as markers with their information.

Now I want to delete a marker with its information from the map with a button or shown in the marker information.

I would appreciate any help. thanks.

**html:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="rest()">Restaurants</button>
```

**code:**

```
var xmlhttp;
var variable;
var be;

var search_group = new L.LayerGroup(); 
var clickArr = new Array();

function rest()
{
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xmlhttp.open("GET","new.php",true);
  xmlhttp.send(); 

  map.addLayer(search_group);

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function restaurant()
  {

    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        variable = jQuery.parseJSON(xmlhttp.responseText);
        for (var i in variable)
        {
            be = L.marker(new L.LatLng(parseFloat(variable[i].lat), parseFloat (variable[i].lon)),options={"id":variable[i].id});
            var container= $('<div />');
            container.html('<b>'+variable[i].name+'</b>'+'<br/>'
        +variable[i].street+'<br/>'
        +variable[i].zipcode+'<br/>'
        +variable[i].city+'<br/>'
        +variable[i].telephone+'<br/>'
        +'<a href=http://'+variable[i].website+'>' 
        +variable[i].website+'</a>');

            be.bindPopup(container[0]);   id="+variable[i].lat+"_"+variable[i].lon+">Remove Marker</a>")
            marker.push(be);    
            be.addTo(map);
        };
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be as simple as storing your markers in an array (looks like your variable `marker` is made for that, even though it is not declared as an array) with same indexes as in your `variable` array, so that you can remember this value in your "Remove Marker" button / link (for example using the HTML5 dataset or jQuery `.data()`) and act accordingly.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/2/